# PostgreSQL ALTER VIEW AS

Tags: postgresql, view, sql-view, alter

I need to alter the view because of the table have been changed

I left the code I used that doesn't work here

```
ALTER VIEW view1
AS
 SELECT bolum.bolumid,
    bolum.bolumad,
    fakulte.ad,
    dersler.dersad,
    dersler.kontenjan
   FROM bolum
     JOIN fakulte ON bolum.bolumf = fakulte.id
     JOIN dersler ON bolum.bolumid=dersler.bolumid;
```

Got an error:`Syntax error near 'AS'`

Comment: This isn't valid syntax, you can't use a SELECT statement in combination with ALTER. Use a different (and valid) syntax or just drop the old view and create a new one. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simply using `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW...`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT a_column FROM a_table;
```